# Producing Strings from Array Multiplication

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multiplication

I am looking to create a javascript function that outputs strings as a result of array multiplication.

The first number of the array will be multiplied by the second, resulting in a string as below.

For ex. when:

```
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]));
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]));
```

The result would be:

```
1111111111
11, 222
```

I am struggling getting past returning simple multiplication out puts such as 1*10 = 10, and producing a full string (w/o commas) instead.

Any advice would be great - thanks.

Comment: Please, add the code you've use to try

Comment: you can also include fiddler for what you have done so far

Answer (score 3):

actually you can do it using a `map` over the `array` and then apply the `repeat` function of `string` (you have to parse from `number` to `string`).

```js
repeatNumbers = (array) => array.map(item => item[0].toString().repeat(item[1]));

console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [1, 10]
]));

console.log(repeatNumbers([
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3]
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array constructor function to create an array of a given length. Then use the `.fill` array method to fill the new array with the right thing. Finally, you can use `join` to convert the filled array back to a string. In your case, for each pair, the first element is what to fill the array with, and the second is the desired length.

Perform that process for each item in the passed array (using `map`), and join them with commas, and you get the result from your example:

```js
function repeatNumbers(arr) {
  return arr
    .map(pair => Array(pair[1]).fill(String(pair[0])).join(""))
    .join(", ");
}

console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 10]]));
console.log(repeatNumbers([[1, 2], [2, 3]]));
```